# How to get value from recursive call using dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make this lookup between two tables. With recursive call. But it always returns None. What could be the reasons ?

```
def checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode):
currCodes = {
    'gbp' : 'GBP/EUR',
    'usd' : 'USD/EUR'
}
retVal = exch_rate[currCodes[currCode]][exch_rate['DAGS']==dt(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc)]
print(retVal)
if retVal.empty:
    dayEc = dayEc-1
    checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode)
else:
    return min(retVal)
```

checkExchangerate(1999,1,17,'usd')
returns None.

```
table exch_rate is pd.DataFrame: 
DAGS         USD/EUR   GRP/EUR 
1999-1-15      0,66    0,4 
1999-1-18      0,65    0,4
```

expected output is 0,66

Comment: Please add example of the two dataframes you are using and expected output.

Comment: if your Dataframe is exch_rate you can passed it as a parameter on your function : 

def checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode,exch_rate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some sample data to your question.

In your code:

```
    if retVal.empty:
        dayEc = dayEc-1
        checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode)
    else:
        return min(retVal)
```

If retVal is empty, it will recursively call itself. But when it comes out of recursion, it does nothing with return value, so it returns None.

To fix that, you should `return` the value that is returned from recursion:

```
    if retVal.empty:
        dayEc = dayEc-1
        return checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode)
    else:
        return min(retVal)
```

Also, you can replace:

```
        dayEc = dayEc-1
        return checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode)
```

with

```
        return checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc-1,currCode)
```

However, instead of recursion, I recommend using a loop:

```
def checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode):
    currCodes = {...}
    retVal = False
    while not retVal or retVal.empty:
        retVal = exch_rate[currCodes[currCode]][exch_rate['DAGS']==dt(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc)]
        dayEc -= 1
        print(retVal)
    return min(retVal)
```

This could cause infinite loop (just as your code could cause infinite recursion), so here's a version with for loop:

```
def checkExchangerate(yearEc,monthEc,dayEc,currCode):
    currCodes = {...}
    retVal = False
    for day in range(dayEc, dayEc-20, -1):
        retVal = exch_rate[currCodes[currCode]][exch_rate['DAGS']==dt(yearEc,monthEc,day)]
        if not retVal.empty:
           break;
        print(retVal)
    if retVal.empty:
        return some_error_code
    else:
        return min(retVal)
```

You can change `20` to be a different number. Or use `range(dayEc, 1, -1)` -- as I suspect that day should never be less than `1`

Comment: no does not work.
also the date has to try lower value.
here is what is returned:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you please add some sample data to your question?

Comment: Oops, I just noticed I forgot to subtract 1 from dayEc in my loop. Try now.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem return was missing before checkExchangerate. 
Thanks you